# Ruby HTMLish tokenizer

Tags: ruby

I'm looking for a resource for tokenizing HTMLish markup. I'm creating a markup language that is a lot like (but isn't) HTML. All I want is something that can parse it up into tags, text, comments, etc. I don't need the tokens to be arranged into a tree structure or checked if they're valid tags or whatever - I'll do that myself.

So, for example, if given this string:

```
hello <x> dude <whatever></x>
```

it would return an array something like this:

```
hello
<x>
 dude
<whatever>
</x>
```

It could also return objects representing those strings. Either would be cool.

I've looked into Nokogiri and Oga, but they seem to just want to parse and tree HTML. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to do much of the validation yourself, could a regular expression work? Something like:

```
html = 'hello <x> dude <whatever></x>'
html.split(/(<[^<>]+>)/)
#=> ["hello ", "<x>", " dude ", "<whatever>", "", "</x>"]
```

Otherwise, I wonder: could your markup be XMLish rather than HTMLish? For example, do you need to support void elements like `<whatever>`, or would it be enough to support self-closing tags like `<whatever />`? That is, are you committed to supporting markup like `hello <x> dude <whatever></x>`, or would supporting `hello <x> dude <whatever /></x>` (with the self-closing `<whatever />`) be enough?

If self-closing tags are enough, it sounds like an XML parser could do the trick. Even if the parser builds a tree, you can usually flatten that into an array.

If you need custom void elements, you may need to find an HTML parser that supports those. I don't know any offhand, but it should be possible to modify Oga to do that. You could also modify Oga to support flattening a tree into an array. Something like:

```
module Oga
  module XML
    # Redefine the list of void elements.
    remove_const :HTML_VOID_ELEMENTS
    const_set :HTML_VOID_ELEMENTS, Whitelist.new(%w{
      whatever
    })

    class TokenGenerator < Generator
      def initialize(*args)
        super
        @tokens = []
      end

      %i[
        on_element on_text on_cdata on_comment on_xml_declaration
        on_processing_instruction on_doctype on_document
        after_element
      ].each do |method|
        define_method method do |content, output|
          token = super(content, '')
          @tokens << token if token
          super(content, output)
        end
      end

      def to_tokens
        @tokens = []
        to_xml
        @tokens
      end
    end
  end
end

html = Oga.parse_html('hello <x> dude <whatever></x>')
Oga::XML::TokenGenerator.new(html).to_tokens
=> ["hello ", "<x>", " dude ", "<whatever>", "</x>"]
```